# Setting NSAttributedString in viewDidLoad causes Scrollview to start in the middle of text rather than top

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've ran into an interesting problem when setting the AttributedString (connected to a UITextView) of a view controller.

In the ViewDidLoad I have the following which overwrites the placeholder text that I have;

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.contentView.attributedText = self.attributedString
}
```

This somehow causes the scrollview to start at the middle of the text displayed, rather than the top.

I've tried shifting the scrollview up by putting [self.contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO] in the viewDidLoad as well, but this doesn't work. Interestingly, I've printed out the CGFloat of the current y position after setting the attributedText, and it prints out 0.

Curiously, I added the same code to print the CGFloat of the current y position in the viewDidAppear, and it's 384 (Middle of screen). Then I added the [self.contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO] and sure enough it scrolled up.

Anyone have any idea why this happens? And how I can make it scroll up to the top in the viewDidLoad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a guess: at `viewDidLoad`, the controller's view has not yet been sized. It'll be loaded, then adjusted to the screen's bounds. `UITextView` is attempting intelligently to keep the same rough area of text on display when it is resized. If it's showing the middle then I'd guess your storyboard or NIB is larger than the device you're displaying on but that's not fundamental to the guess.

It'd possibly be a bit desperate, but maybe ditch `viewDidLoad` and go with:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    if(![self.contentView.attributedText isEqual:self.attributedString])
        [self updateContentViewString];
}

- (void)setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)string
{
    _attributedString = [string copy]; // or no copy, as you prefer
    [self updateContentViewString];
}

- (void)updateContentViewString
{
    self.contentView.attributedText = self.attributedString;
    self.contentView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Or make that even simpler if you want to assume that the text isn't updated once the view controller is visible.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this seems not to work. The text still appears near the middle/bottom. I'm starting to think this is more of an autolayout problem now....

Comment: I'm being thick: are we talking about a large block of text that the scrollview appears to have scrolled to the centre of, or a small block of text that is centred horizontally rather than top aligned?

Comment: I should have stated that, my bad! It's a large block of text that the scrollview appears to have scrolled to the centre of.

Comment: Layout happens after `viewWillAppear:` (which, by the way, requires an argument).  Try `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Putting the self.contentView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0); in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method has made it work! Thanks

Comment: @GoshDangitBobby be careful with `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as e.g. if the device is rotated, the view will change shape and relayout its subviews. So don't always force a scroll to the top there. That's why I was hoping the view had been laid out by the time of `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to scroll to the top of the contentView upon loading your ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // Can add an if statement HERE to limit when you wish to scroll to top
        contentView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
}
```